# How to purge lightdm users list?

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, ldap

The computer is configured with FreeIPA (ipa-client). After a user has logged in for the first time, it is listed on the logon screen. However even when the user has been deleted on the FreeIPA server it still appears in the lightdm logon screen.

Is it possible to purge this list?

EDIT:
Deleting this file does not solve the problem: `/var/log/wtmp`
(From this answer: [how do I remove the last connected users from the lightdm greeter list](https://askubuntu.com/questions/185039/how-do-i-remove-the-last-connected-users-from-the-lightdm-greeter-list))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how do I remove the last connected users from the lightdm greeter list](http://askubuntu.com/questions/185039/how-do-i-remove-the-last-connected-users-from-the-lightdm-greeter-list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By coincidence the `sssd` cache was out of sync and it turned out this was the root of the problem. If you have the same problem, try purging the particular user from the `sss` cache:

```
sudo apt-get install sssd-tools
sudo sss_cache -u username
```